# Am trying to bind the contact id in the contact field by on click the table row

Tags: react-hooks

Am trying to bind the contact id in the contact field by on click the table row. had filtered and bind the data from API in table row. If I click the row want to bind the contact id in the contact field. Here is the code. Please help me to do this.

**Here is the filtered and map function.**

```
const displayList = contact
.filter((contact) => {
  const firstName = contact.firstName;

  const lastName = contact.lastName;

  const fullName = `${firstName} ${lastName}`;

  if (searchTerm === "") {
    return contact;
  } else if (fullName.toLowerCase().includes(searchTerm.toLowerCase())) {
    return contact;
  }
})
.map((contact, index) => {
  const firstName = contact.firstName;

  const lastName = contact.lastName;

  const fullName = `${firstName} ${lastName}`;
  return (
    <tr key={index}>
      <td style={{ width: "1%" }}>{contact.id}.</td>

      <td style={{ width: "5%" }}>{contact.contactID}</td>

      <td style={{ width: "5%" }}>{fullName}</td>
    </tr>
  );
});
```

**Here is the form:**

```
<div className="form-group col-md-6 ml-1">
                    <label htmlFor="Category">Contact Id</label>
                    <Field
                      type="text"
                      className={`form-control form-control-sm ${
                        getError(UserError, Usertouched, "contactId")
                          ? "is-invalid"
                          : ""
                      }`}
                      name="contactId"
                      value={Uservalue.contactId || ""}
                    ></Field>
                    <button
                      className="btn btn-primary openModalBtn"
                      type="submit"
                      onClick={() => {
                        setModalOpen(true);
                      }}
                    >
                      Search
                    </button>
                   
                    {modalOpen ? (
                      <div className="card shadow">
                        <div className="card-body">
                          <div className="row">
                            <div className="col-lg-8 mt-3">
                              <form>
                                <input
                                  type="text"
                                  className="form-control"
                                  placeholder="Search here"
                                  value={searchTerm}
                                  onChange={onChangeSearchTitle}
                                />
                                {/* <button type="submit"><i class="fa fa-search"></i></button> */}
                              </form>
                            </div>
                          </div>
                        </div>
                      </div>
                    ) : null}

                    {searchTerm ? (
                      <div className="table-responsive mt-5">
                        <table className="table table-striped">
                          <thead>
                            <tr>
                              <th style={{ width: "1%" }}>id</th>
                              <th style={{ width: "5%" }}>Contactid</th>
                              <th style={{ width: "5%" }}>Name</th>
                            </tr>
                          </thead>
                          <tbody>{displayList}</tbody>
                        </table>
                      </div>
                    ) : null}
                    <ErrorMessage
                      name="contactId"
                      component="div"
                      className="invalid-feedback"
                    />
                  </div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Using local component state will allow you to achieve this, for example:

```js
function ContactPage() {
    const [contactId, setContactId] = useState()

    ...

    <tr key={index} onclick={() => setContactId(id)}>

    ...
}
```

Comment: If you would like to get any help you have to provide details. What does it mean "it doesn't work"? Did you get any errors? How did you implement the solution? The best you can do is creating CodeSandbox with the issue or providing a link to GitHub.